# Accessing server and mule context objects in Data weave

Tags: mule-component, dataweave

I'm trying to access server and mule version info in DW however I get the below message.

DWL looks like below. Please let me know if I'm making any mistakes below. I have tried both the syntaxes to access it.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
errorType : payload.errorType,
env: server['host'],
host: server['host'],
ip: server['ip'],
javaVersion: server['javaVersion'],
javaVendor: server['javaVendor'],
osName: server['osName'],
osVersion: server['osVersion'],
muleVersion: mule.version,
clusterId: mule.clusterId,
nodeId: mule.nodeId
}

Message               : Exception while executing: 
env: server['host'],
     ^
There is no variable named 'server'.
Payload               : {correlationId=046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91, message=This is the test message to test structured log, errorType=ERROR, applicationName=common wrappers - logging wrapper}
Payload Type          : java.util.HashMap
Element               : /wrapper-logger/processors/1 @ common-wrappers:wrapper-logger.xml:16 (Transform Message)
Element XML           : <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="38c29630-7d7c-48fc-a692-2407d0105cab">
                        <dw:input-payload doc:sample="sample_data\list_HashMap.dwl"></dw:input-payload>
                        <dw:set-payload>%dw 1.0%output application/json---{errorType : payload.errorType,env: server['host'],host: server['host'],ip: server['ip'],javaVersion: server['javaVersion'],javaVendor: server['javaVendor'],osName: server['osName'],osVersion: server['osVersion'],muleVersion: mule.version,clusterId: mule.clusterId,nodeId: mule.nodeId,applicationName : payload.applicationName,correlationId: payload.correlationId,correlationSequence: "To be decided",correlationGroupSize: 5,timeZone: server.timeZone,timeStamp: server.dateTime,muleFlow: "get-user-record",stackTrace: "A complete Stack Trace",message: payload.message}</dw:set-payload>
                        </dw:transform-message>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException: Exception while executing: 
env: server['host'],
     ^
There is no variable named 'server'.
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException$.apply(WeaveExecutionException.scala:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Global function to get the server details and call it from dataweave.

```
<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
    <expression-language>
    <import class = "org.mule.util.NetworkUtils"/>
    <import class="java.lang.System" />
        <global-functions>
            def getServerDetails() { 
            String ip = NetworkUtils.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            String name = NetworkUtils.getLocalHost().getHostName();
            String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
            String osVersion = System.getProperty("os.version");
            String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
            String javaVendor = System.getProperty("java.vendor");
            return [ip, name, osName, osVersion, javaVersion, javaVendor];
            }
        </global-functions>
    </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

Calling from dataweave

```
{
    ip: getServerDetails()[0],
    host: getServerDetails()[1],
    osName: getServerDetails()[2],
    osVersion: getServerDetails()[3],
    javaVersion: getServerDetails()[4],
    javaVendor: getServerDetails()[5]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Abhay. This will be used in a logging component, so it will be heavily used. Can I instantiate this only once when the logging component flow is being started ?. The logging component reads data from VM queue, process each message and logs the data from VM queue along with meta data. It would process a lot of messages, so how can we make it peformance effective ?.  Cant I import these classes directly into DW headers and use it ?Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to import Java classes to dataweave, I tried. by instantiate you mean?